# Removing Spring scoped beans proxy overhead

Tags: spring

How can I customize existing bean injection mechanism so that scoped bean calls method of another bean without additional proxy provided they have the same scope?

I have many nested and performance sensitive loops that call singleton beans and resolve scope of their common data using thread local storage. I'd like to re-factor those singleton scope beans so that instance fields can be safely used.

I will have to change how dependency injection works for those beans. For example, eagerly initialize and set all the references scoped beans when a new scoped bean is created. This should be do-able with a post processor but I need to prevent default wiring from happening in those cases and also retain non-scope related proxies. I have impression that it is going against fundamental Spring design choices and I'm curious whether this idea was intentionally left out.

Comment: When you say "scoped bean" do you mean prototype scoped bean?

Comment: @Ken No, I meant any non edge case scope like singleton or prototype. Request or session scope would be good examples.